# How can I merge and shorten the two questions?

Tags: grammar, comprehension

We provide delivery services and we store or register the addresses of people on our system in a way that addresses are linked or related to phone numbers. I would like to merge those to question?

> Would you like us to contact you on the number you are calling from?
>
> Would you like the delivery guy to arrive at the address that's registered with the phone number you're calling from?

I came up with this but I'm not sure if that's the shortest and correct question :

> Are delivery and contact related to this number?

Comment: What is the question?   Do you want to ask the two questions in a shorter way? Why? "Delivery guy" is problematic. What if the person doing delivery is a girl?.

Comment: James K It's one of the Gulf  (Arab) countries so there are no delivery girls :) Yes, I would like to ask the two questions in a shorter way because I ask them many many times a day. The majority of the answers are yes. I just wanna save some time and headaches. and improve my comprehension skills in English as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two questions can't be shortened without significantly changing the meaning.

I would not understand what you were asking in the shortened question.

The two questions are quite different. I can see no simple way of combining the questions except with "and"

> Can I confirm that we can contact you on this number and that we can deliver to the address that is registered with this number?

As I indicated, you should not use "delivery guy" even in the Gulf.

Comment: *Delivery guy* is a very common phrase. At least in Canada and the US. I'd say it's the most common way of informally referring to a courier. The question of gender neutrality is something completely different.

Comment: It is the gender neutrality that is the issue.  Sure "delivery guy" is fine and common in speech.  But in the written English on the website, or in the formal script to be used when talking to customers, a professional company wouldn't use gender specific language.